# ¿Cómo hacer que esta función de reemplazo en R funcione para dataframes?

Tags: r, funciones, programación-funcional

En muchas ocasiones, cuando trabajamos con bases de datos, encontramos varias codificaciones para datos no registrados o no reportados. Por ejemplo, en pueden ser ceros, -999, -99, entre otras, que, para efectos de tratamiento de datos, podemos convertir en NA.

Pensando en ello, hice una pequeña función que busca que valores no registrados puedan cambiarse por NA:

```
'is.na.m<-' <- function(x, value, ...) {
    x[c(value)] = NA
    x
}
```

Creamos un vector de prueba:

```
x <- c(1:3,2:5,1:10, -99, -999, -98)
is.na.m(x) = x%in%c(-99, -999, -98)
x

Salida:
[1]  1  2  3  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 NA NA NA
```

Ahora bien, intenté que esto funcionara en una dataframe, pero sin éxito:

```
b <-data.frame(animal=c("perro", "gato", -999), num=c(1,-98,3))
is.na.m(b) = b[b%in%c(-98, -999)]
b
```

Como se aprecia, no hay cambios en la dataframe:

```
  animal num
1  perro   1
2   gato -98
3   -999   3
```

** Cabe señalar que `is.na.m(b) = b%in%c(-98, -999)` tampoco dio resultado

Intenté usar la función indexando, pero tampoco resultó:

```
is.na.m(b[,1:ncol(b)]) = b[,1:ncol(b)%in%c(-98, -999)]
b
```

Ahora bien, cuando intento usar lapply, me marca un error:

```
b <- unlist(lapply(b, is.na.m(b))
Error in is.na.m(b) : no se pudo encontrar la función "is.na.m"
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cuáles son los ajustes que debo hacer en la función para que opere correctamente en todas las columnas de una dataframe?

De antemano agradezco cualquier orientación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alejandro, el principal problema que veo es que tienes un confusión con el operador **`%in%`**. Este es un operador binario que apunta a la función [`match()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html), si vemos la documentación de la misma para con el primer parámetro de entrada dice:

> x vector or NULL: the values to be matched. Long vectors are
>   supported.

Es decir, la entrada esperada es un vector, incluso un vector de dos dimensiones (matriz), pero no un `data.frame`, es decir, esto `x %in% c(-99, -999, -98)` funciona como lo esperas, devuelve un vector lógico del mismo tamaño del vector de entrada, pero esto `b %in% c(-98, -999)` ya no, por que `b` es un `data.frame`. Lo interesante y confuso es que no nos da un error, nos devuelve datos, pero no los esperados, el retorno es un vector de `FALSE` del tamaño de las columnas del `data.frame`

```
> b
  animal num
1  perro   1
2   gato -98
3   -999   3
> b %in% c(-98, -999)
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

Te debo la explicación de este comportamiento, `match` es una función interna, escrita en `C` y me falta mucha base de la API R <-> C. De todas formas la conclusión es que no puedes usar `match` de la manera en que lo haces.

El otro problema, no sé si te has dado cuenta de dos situaciones a las que habría que prestar atención:

a. Esto: `c("perro", "gato", -999)` por la coerción automática, se transformará en un vector de cadenas, el número `-999` se promociona a el tipo de dato más general, en este caso una cadena

b. El otro tema, es que por defecto `data.frame()` trata las cadenas como un dato `factor`, esto agrega algo más de complejidad.  Si no quisiéramos este comportamiento deberíamos usar `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Esto te lo comento por que estas buscando hacer un `match()` con valores numéricos, por lo que: ¿Cual debería ser el comportamiento cuando comparamos con cadenas? de hecho esta misma pregunta, al tratarse de un `data.frame` habría que hacerla para cada tipo de dato posible.

Ahora bien, supongamos el siguiente escenario:

```
b <- data.frame(animal=c("perro", "gato", "-999"), 
                num=c(1,-98,3), 
                num2=c(1,-98,3), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b

  animal num num2
1  perro   1    1
2   gato -98  -98
3   -999   3    3
```

Resolvamos el primer problema, como reemplazar los valores `-98` y `"-999"` número y cadena respectivamente. Ya vimos que `%in%` no nos sirve, entonces lo que podemos hacer es comparar por `==` para cada valor buscado:

```
lapply(c(-99, -999, -98), `==`, b)
```

Esto, nos va a generar una lista, dónde cada elemento es una matriz del tamaño del `data.frame` de lógicos por cada valor buscado, y adicionalmente, este operador hace una coerción automática de forma tal que podremos comparar exitosamente (si es lo que buscas) la cadena `"-999"` con el número `-999`. La idea luego es combinar cada matriz en una sola, dónde cada `TRUE` sea el lugar dónde deseamos reemplazar por `NA`

```
Reduce("|",lapply(c(-99, -999, -98), `==`, b))

     animal   num  num2
[1,]  FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]   TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Ahora sí con `Reduce` y combinando las matrices con un `or` lógico obtenemos los lugares que deberemos reemplazar, finalmente:

```
b[Reduce("|",lapply(c(-99, -999, -98), `==`, b))] <- NA
b
  animal num num2
1  perro   1    1
2   gato  NA   NA
3   <NA>   3    3
```

Ahora sí tu ejemplo debería funcionar:

```
'is.na.m<-' <- function(x, value, ...) {
    x[value] <- NA
    x
}

b <- data.frame(animal=c("perro", "gato", "-999"), 
                num=c(1,-98,3), 
                num2=c(1,-98,3), 
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

is.na.m(b) <- Reduce("|",lapply(c(-99, -999, -98), `==`, b))
b
  animal num num2
1  perro   1    1
2   gato  NA   NA
3   <NA>   3    3
```

Comentarios:

- Es un poco raro usar una función de asignación, dónde el valor de que le pasas no es justamente el valor a asignar, es más lógico ver algo de este estilo `is.na.m(b) <- NA`, pero es totalmente válido tu ejemplo.
- No necesitas hacer `x[c(value)]` directamente `x[value]` alcanza.
- Ten en cuenta que cuando usas `is.na.m(b)` sin la asignación, estás llamando a otra función, no a `is.na.m<-()` sino a `is.na.m()` por lo que si no está definida, ahí tienes el error cuando intentas usarla con `lapply`.

Comment: Me pongo de pie (como siempre) ante tu respuesta. ¡Feliz navidad y muchas gracias! :)